# List of generic objects with unknown type

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following two classes. The `ConvertToType<T>` class is an existing class and works fine, however when it is used an instance is created each time (via reflection), therefore I am creating a wrapper class to hold all the instances as they are created for efficiency.

```
public class TypeConverterHelper
{
    private IList<ConvertToType<>> types;
}

internal class ConvertToType<T>
{
    //snip
}
```

However, as you can see I need a list of my `ConvertToType<T>` class, but I can't specify the type as the whole point of these classes is that the type is unknown until runtime. I have researched this issue a fair amount, but without finding a successful solution. I know I could set the generic type to be an object, but there you could get un/boxing issues at some point. Adding an interface/abstract base class which is restricted to a `struct` looked like a good option, but unfortunately `T` could be a string, and possibly other custom classes at a later date so that solution doesn't work.

So does anyone have any other solutions/suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list type has to be non-generic (since the generic type arguments cannot be predicted), so `object` would do, but it might be better to use a common non-generic base. Boxing/unboxing does not come into the discussion because `ConvertToType` is a reference type.

You would of course have to cast the values in the list back to `ConvertToType<T>` before being able to use them; the implementation could look like this:

```
public class TypeConverterHelper
{
    private IList<object> types;

    public ConvertToType<T> GetConverter<T>()
    {
        return types.OfType<ConvertToType<T>>.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than storing it as a mistake-prone `IList<object>`, I would create a non-generic marker interface, `IConvertToType`, and have `ConvertToType<T>` implement it. Then you can store it as `IList<IConvertToType>`.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: While that's probably also what I would do, IMO the only practical benefit is that the code would be more self-documenting (it seems the proposed interface would be completely empty). The list is private and most likely there is exactly one call to `types.Add` in all of `TypeConverterHelper`; it's kind of difficult to write a bug there.

Comment: True, but self-documenting is a fair goal in and of itself.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Agreed on that.

Comment: @Jon Thanks very much for the answer, after a little modification I have it working. I also took the suggestion from @AvnerShahar-Kashtan to create a marker interface, while it is true the `types.Add` is used only once, I prefer to have something other that `object` whenever possible. Again thanks.